# Python text appender

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-editor

The aim of it is to be the quickest way to add to existing notes via SSHh.

Is this code in Python style? Am I missing any methods that would make the code simpler or legible?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

#Maintain: myemail@mail.com
#Purpose: A simple way to add entries to existing files
#Usage: Write the name of the file you intend to add to.
#Future: A list of editable files when the program opens

from sys import argv
import datetime
import os,errno
import os.path
import contextlib

script, typed = argv
filename = typed+".txt"
savelocation = os.path.join('/home/user/',filename)
print(savelocation)
print("Aditor: a digital typewriter, Type: d when done")


date = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
with open("/tmp/tempfile.txt","a+") as target:
        target.write("\n")
        target.write(date)
        while True:
                entry=input()
                target.write("\n")
                if entry in ['done','d']: 
                        break
                else:
                        target.write(entry)

target = open("/tmp/tempfile.txt","r")
f = open(filename, "a")
f.write(target.read())


f.close()
target.close()
print("Entry saved.")


with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    os.remove("/tmp/tempfile.txt")
```

Comment: Why do you need to write the contents to a temporary file in the first place, instead of opening the output file with "a" directly?

Comment: that's a good point, my thinking was, if my connection drops before I am done, it won't affect my the original notes file, but now that you brought it up, it might not make a difference if I write directly to the note.

Comment: That's a fair point, but tangentially, if you're worried about your ssh connection dropping, you should use `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to write to the file directly and want to "apply" the changes at once, instead of writing to a temp file, you can *keep the changes in memory* - in a list of strings:

```
from sys import argv
from datetime import datetime
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _, typed = argv
    filename = typed + ".txt"
    save_location = os.path.join('/home/user/', filename)

    print(save_location)
    print("Aditor: a digital typewriter, Type: d when done")

    date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

    cache = ["\n", date]
    while True:
        entry = input()
        cache.append("\n")

        if entry == 'done' or entry == 'd':
            break

        cache.append(entry)

    with open(save_location, "a") as f:
        f.writelines(cache)
```

Note that I've removed everything related to handling the temp file.

---

Also there were some other changes applied in the code above:

- using 4 spaces for indentation
- used [`_` for a "throwaway" variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) (the script name is not used)
- fixed the variable naming - words need to be separated with an underscore - `save_location` instead of `savelocation` ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))
- checking for "done" using simple comparisons with `done` and `d`
- using `strftime()` to dump a datetime into string
- putting the code to under [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid the code to be executed if imported
- organized imports per PEP8 ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))

Comment: Thanks, I don't know when I would of otherwise started looking at cache and the other techniques you used.